# Only apply RegEx match to leading character based on value of the leading character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Within Rails, For a string that is a hashtag, I want to test that it is valid (alphanumeric and underscores only). But I don't know in advance whether the first character will be `#`

I could test for it:

```
if (string.first == '#')
  string.match(/^[#][\w]+$/)
else 
  string.match(/^[\w]+$/)
```

How would I craft the regex to do the match but only allow the `#` character if it is the leading character?

Comment: The `?` operator indicates either 0 or 1 of the previous character. So `#?` at the start of the regex may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There `?` quantifier in regex, that means `zero or one occurrence`. So, your regexp transforms into:

```
string.match(/^#?\w+$/)
```